# Node-Red how to get function title

Tags: node-red

I'm using node-red for reading data from modbus. I have done own function which converts values to decimal. Now I would like to save those to the REST API, but I need to add key/name of the value in to the database.

Is there way to get Functions node name variable. Which is visibile on ediotr. [image: The name is REGISTER_XYZ]

How I get that name to my function as a variable?

Comment: The node name is not available to the code within the function. But it isn't clear from your question why you want to access it. There may be a better alternative if you can clarify the core requirement.

Comment: This should be the answer. I was looking fro this as well. In my case I wanted to create a nice debug message that was boilerplate enough to copy to multiple functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call a function using its name. Node-red being flow-based programming you have to drop the function Node where you want the transformation to happen in your flow (in-between your HTTP in and HTTP out node very likely). 
[image: flow example]